# `sorted()` objects with custom `__lt__` logic gives inconsistent results

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of strings that I want sorted so that, if string A is entirely contained in string B and B is longer, B is sorted before A; e.g. `abc` would come before `ab` but after `aba`.

To do that, I implemented a class with a custom `__lt__()` method that I can use on `sorted()`:

```py
class Token(str):
    """
    Token class: minimal unit of text parsing.

    This class overrides the `<` operator for strings, so that sorting is done
    in a way that prioritizes a longer string over a shorter one with identical
    root.
    """
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

    def __lt__(self, other):
        logger.debug(f"lt called on {self.content}, {other.content}")

        if self.content == other.content:
            return False

        # If one of the strings is entirely contained in the other string, then
        # the containing string has precedence (is "less").
        if self.content in other.content:
            logger.debug(f"{other.content} comes before {self.content}")
            return False

        # Other way around.
        if other.content in self.content:
            logger.debug(f"{self.content} comes before {other.content}")
            return True

        # If neither of the strings contains the other, perform a normal
        # string comparison.
        logger.debug(f"neither {other.content} nor {self.content} are subs.")
        return self.content < other.content


    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.content)
```

For safety I implemented all other comparison functions, which I have omitted here, but none of them is called in `sorted()` anyway.

then I use a sample `Token` list:

```py
sl = ['ABCD', 'ZABCD', 'AB', 'A', 'BCDE', 'BCD', 'BEFGH', 'ZAB', 'B']
tokens = [Token(s) for s in sl]
sorted(tokens)
DEBUG:lt called on ABCD, ZABCD
DEBUG:ZABCD comes before ABCD
DEBUG:lt called on AB, ABCD
DEBUG:ABCD comes before AB
DEBUG:lt called on A, AB
DEBUG:AB comes before A
DEBUG:lt called on BCDE, A
DEBUG:neither A nor BCDE are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on BCD, BCDE
DEBUG:BCDE comes before BCD
DEBUG:lt called on BEFGH, BCD
DEBUG:neither BCD nor BEFGH are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on ZAB, BEFGH
DEBUG:neither BEFGH nor ZAB are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on B, ZAB
DEBUG:ZAB comes before B

-> ['ZABCD', 'ABCD', 'AB', 'A', 'BCDE', 'BCD', 'BEFGH', 'ZAB', 'B']
```

Some elements have been sorted correctly, some others not (`ZAB` should be before `AB`). It looks like this is dependent on the original order, because if I change the order of the original list, the result is different:

```py
sl  = ['B', 'BCD', 'BCDE', 'BEFGH', 'A', 'AB', 'ABCD', 'ZABCD', 'ZAB']
tokens = [Token(s) for s in sl]
sorted(tokens)
DEBUG:lt called on BCD, B
DEBUG:BCD comes before B
DEBUG:lt called on BCDE, BCD
DEBUG:BCDE comes before BCD
DEBUG:lt called on BEFGH, BCDE
DEBUG:neither BCDE nor BEFGH are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on BEFGH, BCD
DEBUG:neither BCD nor BEFGH are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on BEFGH, B
DEBUG:BEFGH comes before B
DEBUG:lt called on A, BEFGH
DEBUG:neither BEFGH nor A are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on A, BCD
DEBUG:neither BCD nor A are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on A, BCDE
DEBUG:neither BCDE nor A are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on AB, BCD
DEBUG:neither BCD nor AB are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on AB, BCDE
DEBUG:neither BCDE nor AB are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on AB, A
DEBUG:AB comes before A
DEBUG:lt called on ABCD, BCD
DEBUG:ABCD comes before BCD
DEBUG:lt called on ABCD, A
DEBUG:ABCD comes before A
DEBUG:lt called on ABCD, AB
DEBUG:ABCD comes before AB
DEBUG:lt called on ZABCD, BCDE
DEBUG:neither BCDE nor ZABCD are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on ZABCD, BEFGH
DEBUG:neither BEFGH nor ZABCD are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on ZABCD, B
DEBUG:ZABCD comes before B
DEBUG:lt called on ZAB, BCD
DEBUG:neither BCD nor ZAB are subs.
DEBUG:lt called on ZAB, ZABCD
DEBUG:ZABCD comes before ZAB
DEBUG:lt called on ZAB, B
DEBUG:ZAB comes before B

-> ['ABCD', 'AB', 'A', 'BCDE', 'BCD', 'BEFGH', 'ZABCD', 'ZAB', 'B']
```

The order is now different, for example, `ZABCD` comes after `ABCD`. Note that the comparison between the two is not called in the debug statements.

Why would this comparison be skipped depending on the original order?

EDIT: FYI, I'm using Python 3.11.3.

Comment: Your sort is inconsistent, because your sorting criterion is inconsistent. You say "ZAB" should be sorted before "AB", but "AB" would be sorted before "BC", which would be sorted before "ZAB".

Comment: Your example with `abc` and `ab` shows prefix behaviour. Are you sure you don't mean "starts with" (which would result in a consistent sort) rather than "is contained in" (which doesn't, as @tobias_k showed)? If you change `in` to `str.startswith`, do you get what you want?

Comment: For debugging more easier, you can use `["A", "ZA", "X"]` and `["X", "A", "ZA"]`.

Comment: @amadan I am specifically targeting containment, not only staring with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tobias_k mentioned, the criteria you selected are inconsistent, and depend on the order of invocation. `sort` depends on the sorting relation to be a total order, which includes transitivity as one of its requirements. Thus, Python does not need to compare all elements, just enough of them to establish the order. Your comparator violates this requirement: `a < b` and `b < c` does not imply `a < c`. Take the example posted by ken in comments, `["A", "ZA", "X"]` and `["X", "A", "ZA"]`:

For `["A", "ZA", "X"]`:

- Python tests `"A"` vs `"ZA"` and determines `"ZA" < "A"` (containment subrule)
- Python tests `"ZA"` vs `"X"` and determines `"X" < "ZA"` (alphabetic subrule)
- Python assumes that because `"X" < "ZA"` and `"ZA" < "A"`, then necessarily `"X" < "A"` (transitivity, so no test required; ends up violating your alphabetic subrule)
- The order is `['X', 'ZA', 'A']`

For `["X", "A", "ZA"]`:

- Python tests `"X"` vs `"A"` and determines `"A" < "X"` (alphabetic subrule)
- Python tests `"A"` vs `"ZA"` and determines `"ZA" < "A"` (containment subrule)
- Python assumes that because `"ZA" < "A"` and `"A" < "X"`, then necessarily `"ZA" < "X"` (transitivity, so no test required; ends up violating your alphabetic subrule)
- The order is `['ZA', 'A', 'X']`

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for catching the logic flaw.